# MQTT subscribing to 100k retain messages

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

We have more than 100k retained messages for this topic 'devices/access_control/inout_status/by_project/#'. After subscribing, we are receiving around 8k-10k messages and then it disconnects with error 'Broken pipe' and after reconnecting, we are receiving the same 10k messages again. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message delivery is working as intended, you will always get the last retained message for a given topic when you subscribe to that topic.

You are subscribing to a wildcard topic, if you have +10k subtopics under that branch of the topic tree then these messages will always be delivered when you reconnect.

As to why it's dropping the connection with a `Broken pipe` error, this is probably because you can't process that many messages quickly enough and are flooding the receiver to the point where it can't even drive the low level TCP stack.

Comment: Hi...Thanks....Is there any way to add a delay between messages or maybe use another approach such as subscribe.simple to receive messages in batches. For example, first 5k messages will be delivered and then there will be 30 seconds break and other 5k messages will be delivered and so on.

Comment: No, if you want to handle that many messages you will need to design a system capable of handling the load or subscribe to smaller sections of the topic tree

Comment: hey @hardillb, I am using another approach where I want to skip receiving retained messages. For that, I am first connecting to MQTT broker and immediately disconnecting and reconnecting after 1 or 2 secs. This approach is working fine but can I use this approach for a production server? Also, can you give me your skype id or email address for communicating further?

Comment: My private rates are £100 per hour

Comment: I can't afford that right now! Can you please answer the above question here?

Comment: Retained messages will always be delivered to a client when they subscribe to a topic, there is no way to avoid them.

Comment: def on_connect(MQTTclient, userdata, x, rc):
        global first_connect
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected tarun client")
            if first_connect:
                client.subscribe(topic, 0)
                sleep(1)
                client.disconnect()
                sleep(1)
                client.reconnect()
                first_connect= False

Comment: I am able to avoid receiving retain messages by using above code(connect->disconnect(to skip retain messages)->reconnect).....Can I use this approach on production server